# Joomla 2.5 - Set Minimum Password Length

Tags: passwords, joomla2.5

I want to set the Minimum Password length to **8**, but somehow I couldn't able to do that.

I tried changing with the `validate.js` which is at `\media\system\js` by changing regex, but it didn't work.

```
this.setHandler('password', 
                 function (value) {
                 regex=/^\S[\S ]{6,98}\S$/; //Changed from 2 to 6
                 return regex.test(value);
                 }
               );
```

Is there a way to increase the minimum value of Password and Display appropriate message if it is not met.

Comment: can you let me know, what validate.js you are using.. try `minlength="8"` is you are using http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set Password length, there involves two steps,

1. The Condition : Goto `root\components\com_users\models\registration.php`  and Add

   ```
   If (strlen($data['password']) < 8) {
   $this->setError(JText::sprintf('PLG_USER_PROFILE_REGWARN_PASS', $user->getError()));
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. The Message : Goto `root\administrator\language\en-GB\en-GB.plg_user_profile.ini` and Add at the end

   `PLG_USER_PROFILE_REGWARN_PASS="Please enter a valid password of 8 or more characters"`